# How to round values of a vector array

Tags: python, arrays, vector, rounding

I'm working on a Python code and I need to round the values of this following array:

```
P = [[3.2, 3.7, 2.1],
    [4.5, 2.1, 2.3],
    [3.1, 2.5]]
```

And finally get:

```
 P= [[3, 4, 2],
     [5, 2, 2],
     [3, 3]]
```

I tried the following method but it doesn't work.

```
  for i in range(len(P)):
    P[i] = int(round(P[i], 0))
```

Comment: since its a list of list, try doing a second level of iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
P= [[3.2, 3.7, 2.1],
    [4.5, 2.1, 2.3],
    [3.1, 2.5]]

P2 = [[int(round(x,0)) for x in y] for y in P]
# P is your list of lists
# y is each inner list
# x is each element in y
# rounding logic is as yours

print(P2)
```

Output:

```
 [[3, 4, 2], [5, 2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

---

Edit: 2.7 and 3.6 behave differently - I used a 2.7 shell.

See [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

> **Note** The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
>   is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
>   can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point
>   Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

You can fix it by creating your own round-Method:

```
def myRounder(num):
    return int(num)+1 if num - int(num) >= 0.5 else int(num)    

P= [[3.2, 3.7, 2.1],
    [4.5, 2.1, 2.3],
    [3.1, 2.5]]

P2 = [[int(myRounder(x)) for x in y] for y in P]
# P is your list of lists
# y is each inner list
# x is each element in y
# rounding logic is as yours

print(P2)
```

This will lead to the same results on 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: Hello patrick! it works but my output it's not the same as you. I don't know why my console round 0.5 to min value (0, not 1).
You know how to fix it?

Comment: @JuanPablosilvasoler edited, added explanation and fix.